# FreePBX Twilio Peer Details

Tags: twilio, trunk, freepbx

Having issue setting up Twilio Elastic Sip Trunk for outbound route on FreePBX.

We keep getting All Circuits are busy. We are looking for proper registration string and peer details.

Registration times out on trunk repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio has shipped a page that has sample configs for Asterisk that you can use to set up Twilio Elastic Sip Trunks: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/sample-configuration

Your entry for sip.conf will be as follows:

```
[TwilioProvider]
type=peer
secret=password123 ;(your Twilio IP Credentials password)
username=Twilio_UserName ;(your Twilio IP Credentials username)
host=your_business.pstn.twilio.com ;(your configured Twilio Trunk SIP URI)
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
insecure=port,invite
fromuser=14159428007 ;(your Twilio Phone Number associated with this Trunk)
fromdomain=your_business.pstn.twilio.com
context=incoming
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the country is enabled for international calling.

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international